# Why does my constant integer type convert to string?

Tags: php

I have these constants defined in my PHP class:

```
const TYPE_UNDEFINED = -1;
const TYPE_ANNIVERSARY_LIST = 1;
const TYPE_NEW_HIRE_LIST = 2;
const TYPE_EMPLOYEE_BY_NUMS = 3;
const TYPE_MANUAL_LIST = 9;
```

I noticed my code was not acting the way I expected, so I did some debugging.

It turns out, PHP is converting these to String values.

I can force them to be Integer types by using `define()`, but why isn't this working?

We are running **PHP Version 5.3.10**, so `const` should be fine.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You declared class constants, but are accessing a global identifier below (no classname:: prefix).

Comment: You should ALLWAYS enable error reporting for E_WARNING and E_NOTICE. This would have told you that you were accessing the wrong constant.

Comment: As an aside - `switch` in PHP always does loose type comparisons anyway so `case false:` would be equivalent to `case 0:` and which takes effect simply depends on the order in which they appear in the statement - so you can't really depend on the type in a case anyhow.

Comment: @CD001: Recommendations, like skip `0` and `1`, or write the methods differently?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you're doing (apart from that missing `self::` reference of course) so long as you're controlling the possible allowed values in `$this->list_type` (through the setter - don't allow both `0` and `""` and expect to be able to differentiate between them for instance), it's just something to bear in mind - I once tried doing a switch with `case is_int($var):` which, of course, is nonsense :|

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to access these constants using `self::`, so for TYPE_ANNIVERSARY_LIST it would be `self::TYPE_ANNIVERSARY_LIST`

Comment: Thanks. I've coded C++ and C# for 15 years, and this PHP is still causing me basic issues.